# When creating a view in MySQL, how to define a column as the result of calculations using other columns in the same view?

Tags: mysql, create-view

So let's say we have a table called `Prices` with columns `Price1` and `Price2`, and I want to create a View called `Totals` with a column called `PriceTotals` that adds `Price1` and `Price2` on the table, and a second column called `PriceCut` that simply divides `PriceTotals` on the view by 2:

```
create view `Totals` as
   select
     `Price1` + `Price2` as `PriceTotals`,
     /**Put column definition here that divides PriceTotals by 2**/ as `PriceCut`       
   from `Prices`;
```

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
CREATE VIEW Totals AS
    SELECT Price1 + Price2 AS PriceTotals,
           (Price1 + Price2)/2 AS PriceCut
        FROM Prices;
```

Comment: I could do that, but I'm trying to avoid typing the formula twice. I thought that since we already had the result of that formula on a column, I could just reference that column.

Comment: Don't tell me that. Ugh, this is gonna be painful. Thank you though.